# Postgresql: поиск в JSON поле, в значении ключа типа "массив"

Tags: массивы, json, postgresql

Прошу помощи. В таблице два поля: `name(varchar)` и `data(json)`.

Три записи

```
'Петя' '{ "address": ["Москва", "Питер"] }'

'Вася' '{ "address": ["Москва", "Лондон"] }'

'Коля' '{ "address": ["Париж", "Берлин"] }'
```

Сражаюсь с синтаксисом, никак не пойму, как мне запросом выдернуть записи, в массиве address которых есть Москва. как то через приведение к массиву обычному? Чтобы `'Москва' = ANY (array)` припрячь? Или как? Ковыряюсь через

```
 SELECT json_array_elements(data->'address') arr FROM "table" WHERE...(и все, тупик).
```

То тип неправильный, то функции не существует, то еще чо. Помогите плиз, никак не осилю логику

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT json_array_elements(data->'address') FROM arr WHERE data @> '{"address": ["Москва"]}'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Подскажите пожалуйста вдогонку, а как мне добавить и удалить в массиве город? Удаление я пытаюсь провести как `SELECT data::jsonb - 'address'` - грохается пара ключ-значение, а мне нужно только конкретный город убить. Как добавить - не пойму совсем! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Попробуйте так `update arr set data = jsonb_set(data, '{address}', (data->'address') - 'Москва')`

Comment: В лучшем виде получилось! С "добавить" разобрался по аналогу через jsonb_insert. Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: прошу прощения, подскажите а как обновить город. я сейчас делаю "добавить новый", "удалить старый" в массив - но это имхо неграмотно. как мне точечно заменить "Москва" на "Иркутск" к примеру? спасибо!

Comment: Насколько я знаю никак. Либо удалить Москву одной операцией и добавить Иркутск другой, либо полностью перезаписать весь массив.

Comment: Ну значит я правильно делаю. Спасибо за помощь